# Empty spaces in ajax calls jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have Ajax post request and one of the parameters has empty spaces.

```
 $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password));
        },
        data: (
            {
                "id": '1',
                "title": "Character's data",
               ...
            }),
```

Call is successful if I don't have empty spaces in title, but if I do, it is not successful. How to resolve this? Thanks.

//EDIT

I didn't copy it right. This still makes problems if I have this empty space.

Comment: `"Character's data"` - your string literal is not proper

Comment: When is it not successful, in your console or in your code?  In other words, Does the ajax request work in the console at least?

Comment: Yeap it works in REST console, but if I send this call from my code it doesn't work. If I send it without this space in title it works perfectly.

Comment: Then your issue is server side, because if the ajax request is thrown, jquery is not your issue here.

Comment: I will check that, thank u.

Comment: Tried removing opening `(` and closing `)` parens from `data:({})` ?